# how can I enter character "<" in strings.xml?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, escaping

I want to enter string `" -< "` in `strings.xml` file in eclipse, the string has character `<` and I couldn't add it to xml file without error! I even tried to escaping by `\` character:

```
<string name="search_target_arrow"> -\< </string>
```

or enclosing it between `""` as below:

```
<string name="search_target_arrow">" -< "</string>
```

but none worked. Then finally with help of kind users here I found that this would be the correct way to enter such chars in xml:

```
<string name="search_target_arrow"> -&amp;lt; </string>
```

but now when I get this resource in my code:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.search_target_arrow);
```

and set it to a TextView, It shows `-&lt;` on screen! How to get original character by code? should I do something related to HTML?!

Comment: Yrajabi Nambari's solution works for you. try above solution

Comment: @Nambari it didn't work, too! ADT xml editor automatically converted it to < and again raised error when saving the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using eclipse then right click on strings.xml & open it with "Android Common XML Editor" & add from there it will handle escaping for you.

Comment: Thanks, it worked and I found that it converted my string to: -&amp;lt;

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use that string in the code! please take a look at my edited question. What should I do?

Comment: use getText() instead of getString()

Answer (score 0):

Two options

```
&amp;

<![CDATA[&this is my> string and I <can put all the strange symbols I want inside]]>
```

Comment: I tried this but again, as Nambari solution, ADT automatically converts it to < just when I switch to visual string editor tab or when file reopens. So, it raises error on saving.

Answer (score 0):

In the graphical editor (i guess the "Recources" tab), you can type any symbol into the value box, and it'll automatically put the appropriate characters in the xml. So that's good if you don't want to look the codes up.